# Android Studio is not building flutter app correctly

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have an app I'm working on and when I open `build.gradle` file
Several errors appeared

[image]

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.shopapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Console Output:

> Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
>
>   > No version of NDK matched the requested version 20.0.5594570. Versions available locally: 21.0.6113669
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

Also there is a message in logcat
`Please configure Android SDK`
[image]
I looked for a solution and did not find a solution for it

I just need help and don't know if I have violated the laws of the site because I do not speak English fluently

Answer (score 11):

one of the solutions is this,

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.shopapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

ndkVersion "21.0.6113669" ///  <<---Add this, 



}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

The reason is because you have installed other NDK, and android studio has other version, the other solutions is,  -> Go to sdk tools, and uninstall NDK and Cmake.

Sorry for my english, im not native speaker. Good luck!

Comment: That didn't work for me. However, I used the version that the system is saying is available and it worked!

ndkVersion "20.0.5594570"

Comment: Gradle GitHub issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12440#issuecomment-606188282

Comment: I was facing the same issue, after adding the specified version of `ndkVersion` in `/android/app/build.gradle`, there were no build errors.
I added:
`ndkVersion "21.0.6113669"`

Answer (score 7):

This issue is due to incompatibility with the latest android gradle plugin version. You can try to downgrade its version to 3.5.0 in your `android/build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

Comment: i created a new app which created `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'` changing it to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` worked

Comment: please note that the gradle version being used to compile has effect on the version number you should indicate as shown here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 3):

**Modify app/build.gradle with adding ndkVersion**. I have used below version. You have to use your compatible version

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your classpath in **android/build.gradle** to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    ...
}
```

and make sure sure your **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** has

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`

or version as indicacted here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 1):

1. Do check the flutter and dart plugin installed in Extensions inside settings.
2. Then run flutter clean.
3. Run flutter upgrade.
4. If still not working properly add flutter SDK path to environment variable.
5. And i saw an error for services.So do verify the com.google.services in your build.gradle dependencies.
   Hope it work.

Answer (score 1):

modify app\build.gradle file to be like that:
add this inside the android block

ndkVersion "21.0.6113669"

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.1'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ndkVersion "21.0.6113669"

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dawamisr.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to reinstall Android Studio
Taking into account the correct installation of (Java & All packages) from android studio